# Is function call linking between .a's are run time?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I have a doubt regarding the function calls between .a's. Consider I have a workspace, in which two projects are there, each will create .a's and I have added those .a's in main project, now in case if one project have a function call to other project, is it necessary second project's .a should be built with first project to make the link proper, or All linking will happen at run time, so we can add all .a's in main project only?

Hope my question is clear, If not please let me know, I will put more details.

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A static library (.a) is just an archive of object files, i.e. a collection of compiled source files. The linking happens when the main executable is built. So you can create the two static libraries separately, even if one libray has function calls into the other library.